# self.navigationController pushViewController not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have a View application with a Single `UIViewController`. I then add a `UITableViewController` through the IB, and I am trying to display the `UITableViewController` through a button press in the `UIViewController` (my main view). My button press (IBAction) contains the following code through which I am trying to push my `UITableViewController` view and display it:

```
DataViewController *dataController = [[DataViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"DataViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dataController animated:YES];
[dataController release];
```

My `DataViewController` is not at all getting pushed into the stack and displayed, 
Also I have checked that in the code above, `self.navigationController=nil` 
Probably this is the source of the problem. If so, how to rectify it?

Please help.

Answer (score 13):

```
UINavigationController *navCtrlr = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:yourfirstviewController];
[self.window setRootViewController:navCtrlr];
navCtrlr.delegate = self;
navCtrlr.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Create navigation controller in `appdelegate.m` then you can navigate to any `uiviewcontroller`

Answer (score 12):

You need to actually create a `UINavigationController`. The `navigationController` property tells you whether your DataViewController is currently in a `UINavigationController`'s hierarchy; if not (as in this case), the `navigationController` property returns `nil`.

Comment: If I have understood you correctly in my above design, in place of UITableViewController I need to have an UINavigationController and then add an UITableView from the IB. But in this approach, how will I be able to slide in my UINavigationController (through a button press from my UIViewController)? I am a bit confused here. Could you please explain how to go about doing that? My aim is to display a UITableViewController from a button press inside my main UIViewController view. What should be the correct approach here? Thanks again.

Comment: `UINavigationController` is a "controller of controllers," and it's designed to allow you to push and pop controllers and manage a hierarchy of views. You may want to watch lectures 6 and 7 from the [Stanford University "iTunes U" podcast](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/cs193p-student-final-projects/id395605774?i=90218598) for an in-depth explanation of how to use a `UINavigationController` in your app.