# Microsoft Sync Framework Toolkit iPhone example: NSInternalInconsistencyException when loading ListViewController

Tags: iphone, list, frameworks, synchronization, sample

I'm playing with Microsoft Sync Framework iPhone sample, provided with Sync Framework Toolkit available at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e .

I've already corrected request URL's for DownloadChanges and UploadChanges, as mentioned in [Microsoft Sync Framework Toolkit iPhone example - date format wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169754/microsoft-sync-framework-toolkit-iphone-example-date-format-wrong).

Service URL points to the IP address of my local Windows development machine.
I've tried changing it to an instance of Sync Framework Sample Service that I found online at http://www.agronom.pl/ListService with no luck either.

Now the DownloadChanges request works fine, but the List View does not show up.
The following line of code in LoginPage.m:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:listViewController animated:YES];
```

Leads to an exception:

```
exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ListViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

Debug inspector shows the value of [self navigationController] as "Invalid Expression" at the time when exception happens.

I'm a beginner in IOS development, so I can't easily figure out an easy solution from similar questions.
I've tried the following code instead without any luck:

```
        // Create navigation controller. Then we can navigate to any UIViewController
    // --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164525/self-navigationcontroller-pushviewcontroller-not-working?rq=1
    UINavigationController *navCtrlr = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:listViewController];
    navCtrlr.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [navCtrlr pushViewController:listViewController animated:YES];
    [navCtrlr release];
```

Any help much appreciated.